# Go install: Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: go, proxy, http-proxy

Hey I want to install package using `go install`,

But I always get same error:

```
yaoxin@amd-sev-snp2:~/kbs$ go install -v  gopkg.in/yaml.v2@latest
go: gopkg.in/yaml.v2@latest: module gopkg.in/yaml.v2: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2/@v/list": Proxy Authentication Required
```

I have tried suggestions in other questions such as:

```
yaoxin@amd-sev-snp2:~/kbs$ http_proxy=http://10.221.118.171:3128/ https_proxy=http://10.221.118.171:3128/  go install gopkg.in/yaml.v2@latest
go: gopkg.in/yaml.v2@latest: module gopkg.in/yaml.v2: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2/@v/list": Proxy Authentication Required
```

But none of these works for me.

Here is my go env:

```
yaoxin@amd-sev-snp2:~/kbs$ go env
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/yaoxin/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/yaoxin/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/yaoxin/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/yaoxin/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="off"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.20.1"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_FFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-O2 -g"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build255504354=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

I have set up git proxy:

```
yaoxin@amd-sev-snp2:~/kbs$ cat ~/.gitconfig 
[http]
        sslVerify = false
        proxy = http://10.221.118.171:3128
[https]
    proxy = http://10.221.118.171:3128
    sslVerify = false
```

And I was able to git clone repos